# Fundamental matrix correspondence equation results meaning

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, camera-calibration

So i am working on stereo calibration and i have it done already and i believe it is done correctly but there is something i dont understand.

For the correspondence equation that states that `x't.F.x = 0`. I don't get what does this 0 mean? So when i apply this on the detected corners of a checkerboard, i get values of 0.004 or something similar. does it mean an error of 0.004 pixels? or what is its units? I have searched a few computer vision books but they all state that it should be 0 but no further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer:** The reason why you don't obtain 0 is because when the fundamental matrix was estimated, it was done with noisy correspondences, and it was found by inexactly solving an overdetermined system of equations.

**A longer answer:** A fundamental matrix F is a rank 2 homogeneous matrix with 7 degrees of freedom. Each correspondence gives a single constraint on F through the fundamental matrix equation. Noise is inevitable in real situations, caused by both features not being localized perfectly and approximations by modelling camera projection by a mathematical function. It is therefore usually not possible to find F that perfectly satisfies the fundamental matrix equations for all point correspondences. Specifically, this is the situation when there are 8 or more correspondences, because they produce an over-determined system where there are more equations than unknowns. Thus F is found to best fit the equations, leading to some residual error. Having a small residual error of e.g. 0.004 is perfectly normal to me.

The error has no obvious physical or statistical interpretation, and is usually referred to as the *algebraic error*. The reason why the algebraic error is used is because it can be optimized in a least-squares sense using simple closed-form methods (ignoring the rank-2 constraint) with the Singular Value Decomposition [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8f82/bb11ffc2a15244c5cf39b968abce2ab56941.pdf). These solutions are not optimal in a stastical or physical sense, but they tend to work well in practice.

Answer (score 0):

@Toby Collins is correct that the algebraic residual does not have a geometric interpretation. I will try to give you a slightly different way to compute a geometrically meaningful residual.

I will use x0 and x1 instead of x and x'.

Actually, l1=F.x0 gives you a line l1 in image 1. If you scale the line to Hessian normal form (HNF), such that the first two elements of l1 are of unit length, then

err_px1=x1t.l1

will give you a pixel distance from the line in image 1. The problem is symmetric.

l0=Ft.x1

also gives you a line, this time in image 0. You can also convert that to HNF and get the pixel distance in the other image:

err_px0=x0t.l0

In this manner you can compute a meaningful residual, e.g. as a mean pixel distance to the corresponding epipolar lines.